Proving a function is constant, given $U(P, f) = L(P, f)$ for a certain partition
The question goes as follows:

Let $f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Suppose that
there is a partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ such that $L(P, f ) = U(P, f)$.
Show that f is a constant function.

I understood the approach to show $m_i = M_i$ for the partition given considering intervals $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$.
We can do the same for the Greatest Integer Function as well, considering partitions of unit length starting from 0, but we can't say that it's constant too, since for certain other intervals that
$M_i \neq M_{i+1}$,  such as $[\frac{n}{2} , \frac{n+1}{2}]$.
How do we prove that $M_i = M_{i+1}$ as well, besides proving $m_i=M_i$,
or if possible, bypass the above mentioned and still prove the function constant?
Clarification: I wish to know if it is necessary, and possible, to show that every subsequent partition has the same value as its infimum/supremum.

Don't you mean to prove $M_i=M_{i+1}$?

Made the correction, sorry about that.

The greatest integer function doesn't always satisfy the hypothesis of $L(P,f)=U(P,f)$ for some partition $P$. For example, take the greatest integer function on $[0,2]$. Try computing the lower and upper sums for some partitions and you will get the idea of how t see they are unequal for any partition.

Hint: The point $x_i$ is in both $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ and $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$. What does this tell you?
As for your clarification question, it is both possible and necessary.

Oh right, xi is common so the supremum/infimum value follows for the next intervals, if I'm right
